# Blazor virtualize component vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: c#, blazor, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am wondering if it is possible to let the virtualize component work both vertically and horizontally. The documentation is quite vague about it. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0

In the docs it looks like only vertical virtualization is possible. But there are recent commits that show something different. See: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/37585/commits

I made a flex-grid and am trying to get both vertical and horizontal virtualization working at the same time. But it doesn't work: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GFbmlpFU31intdSy24

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not supported? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've the same issue and open a issue on github with a small adjusted example from you for this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39468